# Python/Numpy is 10x slower than MATLAB. Advice on how to speed up?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I have a script that requires multiple loops.  The Python version takes ~88 seconds while the MATLAB version takes ~9 seconds.  I am already using vectorization to remove one of the loops.

MATLAB:

```
ntotal = 2000;
nj = 4000;
r = zeros(ntotal,nj,3);
ncorr = 200;
temp2 = zeros(ncorr,nj);
final = zeros(3,ncorr);


tic
for k = 1:3
    for j = 1:nj
        for n0 = 1:ncorr
            temp1=(r(1:ncorr-n0,j,k)-r(n0:ncorr-1,j,k)).^2;
            temp2(n0,j) = mean(temp1);
        end
    end
    final(k,:) = mean(temp2,2);
end
toc
```

Python:

```
import time
import numpy as np

ntotal = 2000
nj = 4000
r = np.zeros((ntotal,nj,3))
ncorr = 200
temp2 = np.zeros((ncorr,nj))
final = np.zeros((3,ncorr))

t0 = time.time()

for k in range(3):
    for j in range(nj):
        for n0 in range(ncorr):
            temp1 = (r[0:ntotal-n0,j,k]-r[n0:ntotal,j,k]) ** 2
            temp2[n0,j] = np.mean(temp1)
    final[k,:] = np.mean(temp2,axis=1)

t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
```

When I increased `nj` to 10000, the timings became 21 (MATLAB) vs 248 seconds (Python).  Any advice on how to make the Python script run faster?  Thanks.

Comment: MATLAB does a jit compile so you can loop like this without much of a time penalty.  ``python.numpy does not.  You need to use precompiled whole array methods instead.  For a start I'd try to 'vectorize' the `n0` loop.  I wouldn't worry about the small `k` loop.  Replacing loops is a common SO numpy question, but does require some knowledge of numpy.  It's rarely a trivial task

Answer (score 3):

Given the nature of the problem, I would suggest using an appropriate memory ordering, and using Numba.

To begin with, I put your code into a function, so that I had something to compare against.

```
def function_orig(ntotal, nj, r, ncorr, temp2):
    final = np.zeros((3,ncorr))
    for k in range(3):
        for j in range(nj):
            for n0 in range(ncorr):
                temp1 = (r[0:ntotal-n0,j,k]-r[n0:ntotal,j,k]) ** 2
                temp2[n0,j] = np.mean(temp1)
        final[k,:] = np.mean(temp2,axis=1)
    return final
```

(I couldn't tell if temp2 is intended to be a parameter here. It probably ought to be a local variable, but I wasn't sure.)

First thing to notice is that the expression `r[0:ntotal-n0,j,k]` selects many elements on the first axis, and a single element on the remaining axis. This is something which is efficient on column-major arrays, but inefficient on row-major arrays. NumPy uses row-major arrays by default. Matlab uses column-major by default. [More information on memory orderings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).

If you switch to column-major for this one array, it's 2x faster.

```
def function_colmajor(ntotal, nj, r, ncorr, temp2):
    r = np.asfortranarray(r)
    final = np.zeros((3,ncorr))
    for k in range(3):
        for j in range(nj):
            for n0 in range(ncorr):
                temp1 = (r[0:ntotal-n0,j,k]-r[n0:ntotal,j,k]) ** 2
                temp2[n0,j] = np.mean(temp1)
        final[k,:] = np.mean(temp2,axis=1)
    return final
```

Next, I applied a JIT compiler which is frequently helpful for accellerating NumPy-heavy loops, [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). I also turned on `fastmath=True`. See here for an explanation of fastmath: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html#fastmath

```
import numba as nb


@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def function_numba(ntotal, nj, r, ncorr, temp2):
    r = np.asfortranarray(r)
    final = np.zeros((3,ncorr))
    for k in range(3):
        for j in range(nj):
            for n0 in range(ncorr):
                temp1 = (r[0:ntotal-n0,j,k]-r[n0:ntotal,j,k]) ** 2
                temp2[n0,j] = np.mean(temp1)
        final[k,:] = mean_along_axis_1(temp2)
    return final


@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def mean_along_axis_1(array):
    assert len(array.shape) == 2, "array not 2d"
    output = np.zeros(array.shape[0])
    for i in range(array.shape[0]):
        output[i] = array[i].mean()
    return output
```

Timings on my hardware:

```
Original
1min 21s ± 1.46 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1 loop each)
Column major
41.4 s ± 217 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1 loop each)
Numbaized
2.51 s ± 16.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks Nick.  It's good to know about the memory ordering and it's an easy fix.  Numba is a game changer.  I usually try to avoid fastmath.  Without fastmath it is less than 8 seconds, i.e., faster than MATLAB!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to explicitly loop on `j` and `k`.  Here's a tentative rewrite:

```
In [85]: temp2 = np.zeros((ncorr,nj,3))
    ...: for n0 in range(ncorr):
    ...:     temp1 = (r[0:ntotal-n0,:,:]-r[n0:ntotal,:,:]) ** 2
    ...:     temp2[n0,:] = np.mean(temp1, axis=0)
    ...: final  = temp2.mean(axis=1)

In [86]: final.shape
Out[86]: (200, 3)
```

This appears to be much faster, however I did not let your version run to completion; it was taking too long on my small computer.  Also since your `r` is all zeros, there isn't much point in verifying the final `mean` values.

It may be possible to rework the `n0` loop, but since that is only 200, while `nj` and `ntotal` are 4000 and 2000, I wouldn't expect as significant a speed gain.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj.  I was able to verify this method runs faster, on par with the column major trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cython, it's a staticly typed, compiled superset of python, it really makes the code faster, particullary with nested loops. I think you could have a better result than with MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks Maksym.  I don't exactly know how to use Cython.  The suggested Numba method requires minimum code change and seems to be efficient enough.